# String returned by Microsoft Azure Text Translation API causes Parse Error with Windows.Data.Json

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I am currently working on migrating a WPF application to UWP. One of its functions is text translation using the Microsoft Azure Text Translation API. In WPF, I used NewtonSoft.Json and in UWP, I am trying to use Windows.Data.Json. The API is returning the following string:
**"[\" [{\ "" translations \\ ": [{\\" text \\ "": \ "Un travail lourd. \\", \\ "to \\" : \\ "fr \\"}]}] \ "]"**
and the code below returns an invalid Json string error when trying to execute the Parse method.
Any idea what is going on?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
jsonArray.Add(JsonValue.CreateStringValue(responseBody));
string str = jsonArray.Stringify();

JsonObject job = new JsonObject();
job = JsonObject.Parse(str);

var model = new JsonT
{
    TextT = job.GetNamedString("text")
};
```

Comment: That looks like a json object encoded as a json string. Also why at you using a different json api? Newtonsoft.json is supported just fine in UWP apps I thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to use [JsonObject.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject.parse) directly:

```
var response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var job = JsonObject.Parse(responseBody);

var model = new JsonT
{
    TextT = job.GetNamedArray("translations").GetAt(0).GetString("text")
};
```

Though as it has been pointed, https://www.newtonsoft.com/json is a more widely used library, so you may want to use it instead, as there are more tutorials/questions dealing with its use than with UWP Json classes.

Comment: @Voo and Eugene Podskal, thank you for the tips. I really don't know why I decided to change the Json library. I think it was an automatic attitude, I thought it would be necessary, and I didn't bother to test before. Now, I include the code with NewtonSoft.Json and it worked perfectly. What a shame!